# Mxnet - Understanding weight shape for Dense Layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, mxnet

I am understanding Mxnet framework. While following this [Linear Regression article](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter02_supervised-learning/linear-regression-gluon.html) I see the following piece of code which is creating a Dense Layer:

```
net = gluon.nn.Dense(1, in_units=2) # input dimension= 2, output dimension = 1
```

but why does `print(net.weight)` give shape as `Parameter dense4_weight (shape=(1, 2), dtype=None)`

Shouldn't the shape be `(2, 1)`?

According to my understanding:

```
input = Shape(n, 2) where n is number of samples
output = Shape(n, 1)
```

**so the weight matrix should be Shape(2, 1) for the matrix multiplication, isn't it?**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just due to internal implementation. You can think of it as weight matrix is transposed before multiplication.